# Countable union of well ordered sets

Tags: order-theory, ordinal-numbers

Assume I have a sequence $(A_i)_{i<\omega}$ of well-ordered subsets of an ordered set $S$. Assume that $A:=\underset{i<\omega}{\cup}A_i$ is also well-ordered. Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal upper bound on the order types of the $A_i$'s. Does anyone know a condition such that $A$ has order type at most $\alpha\otimes\omega$ (natural multiplication of ordinal) ?

Actually, I know that we can say that $\underset{i=0}{\overset{n-1}{\cup}}A_i$ is well ordered and has order type at most $\alpha\otimes n$. This fact is true since if $U$ and $V$ are well ordered with ordered type $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $U\cup V$ is well ordered with order type (edit : at most) $\alpha\oplus\beta$. I don't have any reference to this fact but many article seems to say that it is known. But it is not known by me. Using this fact, the intuition about my above question should be true, at least for reasonnable condition on $S$ and the $A_i$'s.

Thanks in advanced for reading and (possibly) answering.

Comment: It's not true that $U\cup V$ has order type $\alpha\oplus\beta$, take the union of odd and even numbers, for instance. However, the order type is always *at most* $\alpha\oplus\beta$.

Comment: You are right. It is what I meant, thanks for the correction.

Comment: I initially understood the question as "what are additional conditions to ensure a nontrivial upper bound", but that's quite vague. It's trivial that we can get any countable ordinal (Nik Weaver posted this as an answer); this is not a research-level question.

Comment: Ok let me add some more content. I want to apply with $A_i$ to be the set of the sums of $n$ elements $A_1$ when $S$ is an ordered group. Gonshor has shown that $A$ has order type at most $(\max(\alpha_1,\omega))^{\alpha_1}$ and Ehrlich that it may be at most $\omega^{\omega\alpha_1}$. I want some more hypothesis such that if $\alpha_1$ is less than some multiplicative ordinal then so is the order type of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true in general. Let $\alpha$ be any countably infinite ordinal, let $\phi: \omega \to \alpha$ be a bijection, and let $A_n = \{\phi(n)\}$. Each $A_n$ has order type $1$ and their union is well-ordered with order type $\alpha$.